# Detecting Cursor position in UITextView that contains emojis returns the wrong position in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm using this code for detecting the cursor's position in a `UITextView` :

```
if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange {

    let cursorPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)

    print("\(cursorPosition)")
}
```

I put this under `textViewDidChange` func for detecting cursor position each time the text change.
It is working fine but when I putting emojis the **textView.text.count** is different with the **cursor position**. from swift 4 each emoji counted as one character but it seems that for cursor position it is different.

[image]

[image]

**so How can I get the exact cursor position that matches the count of characters in a text ?**

Comment: Seems like you're using some `UITextView` extension. Can you share the code of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story short: When using Swift with `String` and `NSRange` use this extension for Range conversion

```
extension String {
    /// Fixes the problem with `NSRange` to `Range` conversion
    var range: NSRange {
        let fromIndex = unicodeScalars.index(unicodeScalars.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let toIndex = unicodeScalars.index(fromIndex, offsetBy: count)
        return NSRange(fromIndex..<toIndex, in: self)
    }
}
```

Let's take a deeper look:

```
let myStr = "Wéll helló ⚙️"
myStr.count // 12
myStr.unicodeScalars.count // 13
myStr.utf8.count // 19
myStr.utf16.count // 13
```

In **Swift 4** string is a collection of characters (composite character like **ö** and emoji will count as one character). **UTF-8** and **UTF-16** views are the collections of UTF-8 and UTF-16 code units respectively.

Your problem is, that **textView.text.count** counts collection elements (emoji as well as composite character will count as one element) and `NSRange` counts indexes of UTF-16 code units. The difference is illustrated in the snipped above.

---

More here:
[Strings And Characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)